# Replace URL with valid ID

Tags: php, regex

I have a **PHP** String **$menu** with lots of links. I need to replace the href with an ID based on the link.

I need to

- remove the domain
- remove Slashes at the begining and the end
- replace Slashes in the middle with '-'

This i what I have:

```
<a href="http://www.test.de/start/">Link</a>
<a href="http://www.test.de/contact/">Another Link</a>
<a href="http://www.test.de/contact/sub/">Sub Link</a>
```

And this what I want:

```
<a href="#start">Link</a> 
<a href="#contact">Another Link</a>
<a href="#contact-sub">Another Link</a>
```

I tryed it with **preg_replace**

```
$search = array(
    "/http:\/\/www.test.de/",
    "/".preg_quote('/">', '/')."/"
);
$replacement = array('#','">');
$menu = preg_replace($search,$replacement,$menu);
```

My solution looks a little bit "dirty and doesn't replace the Slashes in the middle. **Any ideas for a "real" pattern to get this done?**

Comment: Is the domain always the same?

Comment: To make things easier, you can use `preg_replace_callback` and broadly match `<A ...>` tags. Then rewrite their innards with a multiple `str_replace()`. This is quick, and will work, but **will only work in the easy scenario** where all your links are made that way. If you start having more complex tags, maybe with inline styles or Javascript that introduce *spaces* and *escaped quotes*, regexps will not work, and Jack's solution is your only practical recourse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be easily done with DOM parsing:

```
$html = <<<EOM
<a href="http://www.test.de/start/">Link</a>
<a href="http://www.test.de/contact/">Another Link</a>
<a href="http://www.test.de/contact/sub/">Sub Link</a>
EOM;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor) {
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    if (strpos($href, 'http://www.test.de/') === 0) {
        $href = '#' . strtr(trim(parse_url($href, PHP_URL_PATH), '/'), '/', '-');
        $anchor->setAttribute('href', $href);
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Oi3aWK)

Comment: +1 for the most robust solution (regexp for HTML parsing is BAD: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags )

Comment: Yes, the domain is always the same.Thanks for your great tipps - I will try it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the php function [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php); to create an array of the url segments.

ie:

```
$url = 'http://www.test.de/contact/';
$urlinfo    = parse_url($url);

echo "<h2>URL INFO</h2><pre>";
print_r($urlinfo);
echo "</pre>";
// create the id to be used
$linkID = "#".str_replace('/','',$urlinfo['path']);
echo $linkID;

// OUTPUT
<h2>URL INFO</h2>
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => www.test.de
    [path] => /contact/
)
#contact
```

M

Answer (score 0):

If the domain is always the same try:

```
str_replace("http://www.test.de/","#", $menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove the domain
$menu = str_replace("http://www.text.de","",$menu);

// Remove the beginning / and add #
$menu = str_replace("\"/","\"#",$menu);

// Remove the trailing /
$menu = str_replace("/\"","\"",$menu);

// Replace all remaining / with -
$menu = str_replace("/","-",$menu);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Change fixed-name domain to #
- Trim / from the end
- Replace / with -

  ```
  $domain = "http://www.test.de/"
  str_replace('/','-',trim(str_replace($domain, '#', $menu),'/');
  ```